# AttributeError in python-rtmidi sample code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, midi, python-3.5

I installed rtmidi for python and was able to import it. But when I tried to run the whole usage example given here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rtmidi, I got this error:

AttributeError: 'rtmidi_python.MidiOut' object has no attribute 'get_ports'

Here's the full code:

```
import time
import rtmidi_python as rtmidi

midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
available_ports = midiout.get_ports()

if available_ports:
    midiout.open_port(0)
else:
    midiout.open_virtual_port("My virtual output")

note_on = [0x90, 60, 112] # channel 1, middle C, velocity 112
note_off = [0x80, 60, 0]
midiout.send_message(note_on)
time.sleep(0.5)
midiout.send_message(note_off)

del midiout
```

I modified the code a little bit in the import part, because somehow it doesn't work when I put `import rtmidi` but works when I put `import rtmidi_python`.

I'm using Python 3.5. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The reason you're having trouble is that you are running sample code for [python-rtmidi](https://github.com/SpotlightKid/python-rtmidi/), but you installed [rtmidi-python](https://github.com/superquadratic/rtmidi-python). I kid you not, these are two separate libraries that do the same thing with almost the same interface. It's nuts! You have two options:

1. you can install the correct library by doing: `pip install python-rtmidi`
2. you can modify your code so that it works with `rtmidi-python` as follows:

   ```
   import time
   import rtmidi_python as rtmidi

   midiout = rtmidi.MidiOut()
   available_ports = midiout.ports

   if available_ports:
       midiout.open_port(0)
   else:
       midiout.open_virtual_port("My virtual output")

   note_on = [0x90, 60, 112] # channel 1, middle C, velocity 112
   note_off = [0x80, 60, 0]
   midiout.send_message(note_on)
   time.sleep(0.5)
   midiout.send_message(note_off)

   del midiout
   ```

You see: instead of doing `get_ports()`, you simply references the `ports` attribute.

Comment: it's actually even more nuts than that, there's also [pyrtmidi](https://github.com/patrickkidd/pyrtmidi) which has a third, slightly different, syntax. Even worst, now both *pyrtmidi* and *python-rtmidi* use the same module name: `rtmidi`. I'm stuck finding a way for my program to differentiate between the two...